# window.open on second monitor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

```
window.open('branchMonitoring/', 'Testing Dual Monitor', 'resizable=1, scrollbars=1, fullscreen=0, height=200, width=650, screenX=0 , left=1280, toolbar=0, menubar=0, status=1');
```

I used this code to open a new window on second monitor but the new window still opens on first monitor and cannot exceed the first monitor's boundary. I tried to change "left" to a higher value but still no luck.

Please help me brothers. i am using latest google chrome browser and using windows 8 dual monitor.

Please do note that this solution works for me when using FireFox browser. But I need to get it work on chrome.

Comment: JavaScript cannot know where your second screen is located at though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get JavaScript to open a popup window on the current monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652/how-do-i-get-javascript-to-open-a-popup-window-on-the-current-monitor)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 i think you can position the newly opened window by setting "left" attribute. but when I set it to 1280(my primary monitor's width) the window is still stucked at the first monitor.

Comment: brothers i found some remedy on my prolem.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57303963/1497139 how you can select a monitor with presentation-api in chrome and potentially other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing many researches, I found some remedy. Some are saying that this is a bug on chrome.

please refer too this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972796/2276894

And also if you are targeting to create an admin/internal application, you can  try **Chrome App**. It offers functions like, `window.create()` with position parameters. You can control the position of the windows you created. Remember that you have to install the **Chrome App** you created in user's browser, just like in extensions.

Comment: Chrome Apps are now deprecated by Google.