# Open SCORM popup in the other screen

Tags: php, moodle

I have implemented SCORM in one of my applications and it works perfectly. I am using two screens for development purposes and i want to open SCORM pop-up in the other screen whereas the application will be on screen one(from where the request to open SCORM will be made).

Is it somehow possible to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome's had a issue with this for a bit - [popup open position in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754260/popup-open-position-in-chrome/17972796#17972796).

Also [How do I get JavaScript to open a popup window on the current monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652/how-do-i-get-javascript-to-open-a-popup-window-on-the-current-monitor).

You should be able to use the screen left position though to work out the math.  I did something like this to get the window to appear to the left of the browser window.  Again, Chrome may be a issue.

```
leftPosition = (window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX) - width;
topPosition = 0;
window.open(url, "Title", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
```

Comment: where we have to change this on?in which file?

Comment: The LMS typically launches content and that's entirely proprietary.  So for locating the code I would just search for "window.open" across the entire codebase on moodle.

Comment: ok..i have another doubt..how to open the scorm package directly from my appplication(php)..i used moodle sessions.do you have any idea..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but maybe add `windowobj.moveTo(xxx, yyy);` in `/mod/scorm/player.js` where xxx is the number of pixels to the other screen