# Open new window in secondary monitor in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i open a new popup window in secondary monitor using JavaScript , i try with this code no success.

```
function FindLeftWindowBoundry() {
        if (window.screenLeft) {
            return screen.width;
        }
        if (window.screenX)
            return window.screenX;
        return 0;
    }

window.leftWindowBoundry = FindLeftWindowBoundry;

function FindLeftScreenBoundry() {
    if (window.leftWindowBoundry() > window.screen.width) {
        return window.leftWindowBoundry() - (window.leftWindowBoundry() -
            window.screen.width);
    }
    if (window.leftWindowBoundry() < 0 && window.leftWindowBoundry() >
        (window.screen.width * -1)) {
        return (window.screen.width * -1);
    }
    return 0;
}
window.leftScreenBoundry = FindLeftScreenBoundry;
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652/how-do-i-get-javascript-to-open-a-popup-window-on-the-current-monitor

Comment: @surekhashelake my question is to open new window in secondary(extended) monitor ,not in same monitor